# The Rails.root.join will miss the Rails.root path in some conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The absolute path I want is `/Users/Hsu-Wei-Cheng/Dropbox/Rails/zeus/public/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip`

The `/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip` is stored in `local_display_multi_lang.result`

So I tried to use the `Rails.root.join` method to get the absolute path in my system.

By `Rails.root.join("public", local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s)`

But it didn't work, I got `:/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip`

What's the mistake I made? Thanks

```
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> Rails.root.join("public", local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s)
=> #<Pathname:/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip>
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> Rails.root
=> #<Pathname:/Users/Hsu-Wei-Cheng/Dropbox/Rails/zeus>
[5] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s
=> "/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip"
[6] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> Rails.root.join("public")
=> #<Pathname:/Users/Hsu-Wei-Cheng/Dropbox/Rails/zeus/public>
[7] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s
=> "/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip"
[8] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> Rails.root.join("public", local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s)
=> #<Pathname:/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip>
[9] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe7ae84f038>>)> Rails.root.join("public", local_display_multi_lang.result)
=> #<Pathname:/uploads/local_display_multi_lang/xml/8/results.zip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s` is an absolute path.

Try

```
Rails.root.join("public", local_display_multi_lang.result.to_s[1..-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, But now I have some in absolute path some in relative path. Is there any builtin function can fix?